# Getting Android acceleration and show on screen

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to get accelerometer values and show on screen. Even though I dont get any error, I cant see any value being sent to the text object. 
When installing I have vibration permission and those should be all good.

```
package com.example.sendsms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    SendSMS mSender = new SendSMS();
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private float mSensorX;
    private Sensor mSensor;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

         mSensorX = event.values[0];
        String temp = Float.toString(mSensorX);
        //mSensorY = event.values[1];
        TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xacc);
        resultText.setText(temp);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         // Get an instance of the SensorManager
        this.sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        this.accelerometer = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    }


    public void sendit(View v) {
        boolean success = mSender.sendSMSMessage("0413556955",
            // This is standard lorem-ipsum text, do not bother
            // trying to wrap it, there's about 500 characters...
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent " + (
            success ? "successfully" : "unsuccessfully"), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xacc);
            resultText.setText("Message Sent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for listener.

```
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }
```